# C array size given by variable

Tags: c, arrays

I found some code today that confused me. 
It did something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int x = 5;
    int foo[x];

    foo[0] = 33;
    printf("%d\n", foo[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

**My Question is why does this work?**

The array `foo` is on the stack so how could it be expanded by `x`?

I would have expected some thing like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int x = 5;
    int foo[] = malloc(sizeof(int)*x);

    foo[0] = 33;
    printf("%d\n", foo[0]);
    free(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Not that it is prettier or something but, I just wonder.

Comment: It's called a Variable Length Array (VLA). It's part of C since C99.

Comment: This is new in C99. I was also astonished when saw this first time. It is not normal for C way of "thinking". At least, it is not good idea to put (big) arrays in stack.

Comment: That is the better version of `alloca`. (there are differences in persistence, however)

Comment: KISS-Answer: because c99 rules :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The snippet

```
int foo[x];
```

is talking advantage of something called VLA ([Variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)) feature. It was introduced in `C99` standard, just to be made an optional feature in `C11`.

This way, we can create an array data structure, whose length is given (supplied) at run-time.

Point to note, though created at runtime, `gcc` allocates the VLAs on stack memory (unlike the dynamic memory allocation from heap memory).

Comment: Thanks that explains it. We have to be gcc 2.9.5 compatible couse we have platforms with a 386 processor so VLA will not work ;). Thanks.

Comment: @maxbit89 gcc has always had an extension to do variable-length arrays (although with different behaviour to Standard C ones)

Answer (score 2):

> The array foo is on the stack so how could it be expanded by x?

gcc simply moves the stack pointer:

```
subq    %rax, %rsp
```

[Link to full example with assembly output](http://goo.gl/OOxx1e)