# How to define array size based upon number of inputs?

Tags: c, arrays, variable-length-array

As far as my knowledge, (im a beginner in c) you can define the size of an array provided the user knows how many inputs the user is going to provide. But, how can i define the size of an array based upon number of inputs?

For example, if I have to give 10 numbers as input, then how do i declare an array in such a way that its size is assigned as 10 based upon the count of my input? (i don't know if it is possible but yet i want to find out)

Comment: That is something called memory allocation and it is not beginner level. If you're really interested then google for malloc, calloc and realloc. But If you are really beginner just keep studying, that will come later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with C99 you can use variable-length arrays. You can declare them as you go, using a `size_t` variable for its size.

```
size_t n;
printf("How many numbers would you like to enter?\n");
scanf("%zu", &n);
int array[n];
for (size_t i = 0 ; i != n ; i++) {
    printf("Enter number %zu: ", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
}
printf("You entered: ");
for (size_t i = 0 ; i != n ; i++) {
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/VgYwgx)

**Note :** This approach works for relatively small arrays. If you anticipate using larger arrays, do not use this approach, because it could lead to undefined behavior (overflowing the automatic storage area). Instead, use `malloc` and `free`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should go over pointers concept in C .
[you can go through these videos](http://youtu.be/ynYtgGUNelE)

While allocating  memory for 1d arrays dynamically pointers are quite handy.

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: @ForeverStudent: this is a possible answer to the question asked, since he is a beginner in C so if i write a C code using pointers to answer his query it would be difficult for him to understand in a single go. I thought it would be best if he gets to know about pointers and understand it this way:) . Please correct me of i am wrong

Comment: linking to an outside resource can be helpful, but it is not an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly make use of [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (introduced in `C99`), but be aware, in the latest standard `C11`, this had been made an *optional* feature. Latest compilers are not *bound* to support this feature in future. If you are interested, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31654569/2173917).

The best way to go is to make use of pointers and dynamic memory allocation functions like [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family.

Example: *(pseudo-code)*

```
int * p = NULL;
int input = -1;
scanf("%d", &input);
p = malloc(input * sizeof*p);
if (p) { .....
```

here, you can control the allocation size using the `input` variable value.

*P.S- Pointers are not arrays, for sure, but I believe, for most of the cases, this will serve the purpose.*